# What is wrong with this code. Why can't I use SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlclient

I am 100% newbie to SQl and wanted to make a ConsoleApp with the use of database. I read some about it and tried. When I needed to make SqlConnection, my VS 2019 Preview showed me this

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error
>       CS1069  The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'.
>    This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
>       ConsoleApp1 C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bald Code\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  12
>       Active

i don't get why it doesn't work

Here's my code

```
using System;

using System.Data;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp1

{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add the System.Data.SqlClient assembly in your project reference.

Answer (score 56):

If you just updated [EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) from version 2.x to 3.x and you're running into this, change your `using` statement to [***Microsoft**.Data.SqlClient*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) instead of [***System**.Data.SqlClient*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/).

If you're using [*EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) it already has that as a dependency, so you shouldn't need to install it explicitly.

[This Microsoft blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/) explains the change.

> The Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package, ... , will be the flagship data access driver for SQL Server going forward.

and

> We have no intention of dropping support for System.Data.SqlClient any
> time soon (written in 2019). It will remain as-is and we will fix important bugs and
> security issues as they arise. ...
>
> However, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient will be the only place we will be
> implementing new features going forward.

Comment: Not working... Microsoft doesn't have Data.SqlClient in it.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/2.0.1

Comment: Working in vscode on a C# .NET core project, I opened a new terminal window and executed this at the command line -

"dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient"

The compiled software can now access the database in the expected manner.

Answer (score 34):

Most likely the  System.Data.SqlClient.DLL in not in the Bin folder, and you have not set reference to the DLL in the project. You have missed the database choice when You install visual studio. And now You just manually add references named "System.Data.SqlClient".

1.right click you project name and choose nuget package options.

2.search "System.Data.SqlClient" and install it.

[image]

Hope this is fix Your Error

Answer (score 25):

Assuming that you're using .NET Core - just add NuGet package: `System.Data.SqlClient`

Your .csproj might look similar to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem despite adding the package from NuGet in VS2017.  I had to close the project and re-open it for System.Data.SqlClient to be recognized.

Answer (score 13):

The specific way to fix this from within VS Code is to

1. Open a terminal by going to Terminal -> New Terminal
2. Run dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient
3. Run dotnet restore

That last command might not be necessary, but doing this made it work for me. It seems that console app templates don't come prepared for a reference to SqlClient.

**Update**

I think moving forward projects should use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and not System.Data.SqlClient: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/.

Answer (score 3):

As @Mmm mentioned in the comments if you are using .NET Core and have already installed the System.Data.SqlClient package, closing and reopening the project resolved the issue for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error today and what's happening its that VS CODE its no recognizing System.Data.SqlClient;, that's why you can't call the variable...

How did I fix it??

### I installed:

- SQL server compact toolbox
- Nuget Package version updater

Close visual studio/Open it again and your program should be rocking and popping!!

Answer (score 0):

[!["Manage Nuget Package for Solution"]

it fixed my issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpk2e.png

I just installed nuget package from the "Manage Nuget Package for Solution". Previously I had used through command but that did not work so I used the UI to install this package.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple

Go to solution explorer > right click & click manage NuGet packages > and install System.data.SqlClient 4.5.1. or later.

[Click here to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thZXk.png)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. You answer is the same as many of the previous ones and does not add anything new or helpful to the post. When you have enough reputation, you could upvote an existing answer instead of duplicating it which you should avoid

Answer (score 0):

NuGet Package

```
Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient
```

solve my problem.

Comment: how do you get to this command line where you can type this command in?

Answer (score 0):

For me System.Data.SqlClient was already installed. What i had to do was, I went to the Nuget package manager and downgrade the version to 4.8.2 from 4.8.3 and it worked.

Comment: 4.8.2 did not work for me. At runtime I get an error expecting 4.6.1.2

Answer (score 0):

If none of the previous solutions has worked for you then try changing the version of `System.Data.SqlClient` in the project file to `0.0.0` or `4.1.0` because this is what the error is saying to use this version. After you change the version compile the code and once compiled then you can change the version of the library to the original one.

Note: The current version of the library I had was `4.8.5`. Also, I tried all of the above solutions but none worked for me except for this one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem in my .NET MAUI application targeting .NET 8.0; my Android application wouldn’t compile after I installed the System.Data.SqlClient package from NuGet. But after uninstalling it and installing the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package instead, the problem was resolved.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```